# Why is SDL_HasMMXExt missing in SDL2

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, cpuid, mmx

In SDL 1.2, there is `SDL_HasMMXExt`. See [here](http://libsdl1.2.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.2.14-6.1ubuntu3/SDL__cpuinfo_8h_a902f17f22ea2c4af471ebc07f2817ece.html). The full source of the file can be seen [here](http://libsdl1.2.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.2.14-6.1ubuntu3/SDL__cpuinfo_8c_source.html).

In SDL 2, that function is missing. Why? The full source of SDL2 of the same file can be seen [here](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/e69eb33a5e376fe7679afdce29385464603f6666/src/cpuinfo/SDL_cpuinfo.c).

Relevant code of SDL 1.2 is this:

```
static __inline__ int CPU_haveMMX(void)
{
      if ( CPU_haveCPUID() ) {
            return (CPU_getCPUIDFeatures() & 0x00800000);
      }
      return 0;
}

static __inline__ int CPU_haveMMXExt(void)
{
      if ( CPU_haveCPUID() ) {
            return (CPU_getCPUIDFeaturesExt() & 0x00400000);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

`CPU_getCPUIDFeaturesExt` is also missing in SDL2.
Why was it removed?